# Dúvida na implementação da busca em profundidade em Grafos

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados, grafo

Estou estudando para uma prova de algoritmos e acabei encontrando alguns problemas para implementar o *DFS*(*Depht-First Search*/busca em profundidade) utilizando a estrutura de dados *Pilha*.

```
static void emProfundidade(ArrayList<Node> grafo, Node origem) {
    Stack<Node> pilha = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < grafo.size(); i++) {
        grafo.get(i).visitado = false;            
    }

    pilha.push(origem);
    origem.setVisitado();

    while (!pilha.isEmpty()) {
        Node v = pilha.peek();
        System.out.println(pilha);

        for(int i = 0; i <v.adjacencias.size(); i++){
            Node adj = v.adjacencias.get(i);
            if(adj.visitado == false){
                System.out.println(v + " >> "+adj);
                pilha.push(adj);
                adj.setVisitado();
            }                
        }
        pilha.pop();
    }
}
```

O grafo que estou tentando realizar a busca é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando como estrutura uma lista de listas para a construção do grafo.
A impressão das arestas é a seguinte:

```
A >> [B, C, D]
B >> [A, E, C]
C >> [A, B, D, F, G]
D >> [A, C, G]
E >> [B, F, H]
F >> [C, E, I]
G >> [D, C, J]
H >> [E, I, L]
I >> [F, H, L]
J >> [G, I, L]
L >> [H, I, J]
```

O problema é: aparentemente a pilha só está conseguindo ir/alcançar o vértice `E`. Inicialmente achei que as referências dos arcos pudessem estar erradas, porém os vértices estão corretamente ligados entre si. A saída, de quando eu imprimo na tela a pilha é a seguinte:

```
[A]
[A, B, C]
[A, B, C, F]
[A, B, C, F, E]
[A, B, C, F, E]
[A, B, C, F]
[A, B, C]
[A, B]
[A]
```

O engraçado é que, quando eu removo o `pilha.pop();` após o laço, o conteúdo da pilha é o resultado do maior caminho, porém o código entra em *loop*:

```
[A, B, C, D, G, J, I, L, H, E, F].
```

Implementação da classe Node:

```
private static class Node {

    String valor;
    ArrayList<Node> adjacencias;
    boolean visitado;
    int maiorSeq;
    Node refMaxNextNode;
    char color;
    int dist;
    Node pai;

    Node(String valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
        adjacencias = new ArrayList<>();
        visitado = false;
        maiorSeq = 0;
        refMaxNextNode = null;
        dist = 0;
    }

    void setValor(String valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    boolean addCaminho(Node outroNode) {
        if (adjacencias.contains(outroNode)) {
            return false;
        }

        adjacencias.add(outroNode);
        return true;
    }

    void setVisitado() {
        this.visitado = true;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "" + valor;
    }

    public void pai() {
        System.out.println("O pai de " + valor + " é: " + pai);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Podes colocar a definição da classe Node?

Comment: Implementação adicionada :)

Answer (score 4):

O problema está na local onde se encontra a instrução `pilha.pop()`. Este output deveria dar-te uma indicação de onde se encontra o problema:

```
[A]
[A, B, C]
[A, B, C, F]
[A, B, C, F, E]
[A, B, C, F, E]
[A, B, C, F]
[A, B, C]
[A, B]
[A]
```

Se reparares o D é um nó adjacente ao A mas não está na pilha.

Vou mostrar porquê. Assume que o **A é o nó origem**. No início do teu algoritmo colocas este nó na pilha e marcas como visitado:

```
pilha.push(origem);
origem.setVisitado();
```

Depois procuras todos os nós adjacentes ao A que ainda não foram visitados. Como é a primeira iteração B, C e D nunca foram visitados. Após a execução do ciclo

```
for(int i = 0; i <v.adjacencias.size(); i++){
    Node adj = v.adjacencias.get(i);
    if(adj.visitado == false){
        System.out.println(v + " >> " + adj);
        pilha.push(adj);
        adj.setVisitado();
    }                
}
```

A tua pilha contém **[A, B, C, D]**.

O problema vem agora. Imediatamente após colocares o último nó adjacente ao A (neste exemplo o D), removes esse nó da pilha com a instrução `pilha.pop()`.

Sendo que a tua pilha passa a **[A, B, C]** e acabaste de perder o nó D.

Podes solucionar esse problema alterando o local onde removes o elemento do topo da stack, por exemplo:

```
static void emProfundidade(ArrayList<Node> grafo, Node origem) {
    Stack<Node> pilha = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < grafo.size(); i++) {
        grafo.get(i).visitado = false;            
    }

    pilha.push(origem);
    origem.setVisitado();

    while (!pilha.isEmpty()) {
        Node v = pilha.pop(); //substituir o peek pelo pop
        System.out.println(pilha);

        for(int i = 0; i <v.adjacencias.size(); i++){
            Node adj = v.adjacencias.get(i);
            if(adj.visitado == false){
                System.out.println(v + " >> "+adj);
                pilha.push(adj);
                adj.setVisitado();
            }                
        }
        //pilha.pop();  -- Remover daqui
    }
}
```

Edit:

Este será o conteudo da pilha durante a execução do programa (depende da ordem pela qual visitas os nós)

```
[A]              - No inicio do algoritmo colocamos o A na pilha
[B, C, D]        - Após o ciclo for, todos os nós adjacentes a A estão na pilha. Repara que o A foi removido da mesma
[B, C, G]        - Na próxima iteração vamos procurar os nós adjacentes ao último nó visitado, neste caso o D. Ele tem três nós adjacentes, mas como o A e o C já foram visitados apenas colocamos o G no topo da pilha. E é o G o próximo nó que processamos (DFS).
[B, C, J]        - Após processar o G que tem 3 nós adjacentes, mas uma vez mais dois deles já foram visitados, por isso só colocamos o J na pilha.
[B, C, I, L]     - Após processar o J
[B, C, I, H]     - Após processar o L
[B, C, I, E]     - Após processar o H
[B, C, I, F]     - Após processar o E
[B, C, I]        - Após processar o F, que é o primeiro nó que não tem adjacentes não visitados. Aqui começamos a fazer backtrack
[B, C]           - Após processar o I
[B]              - Após processar o C
```

Como podes verificar todos os vertices foram visitados e o B e o C, que foram os primeiros nós a ser colocados na pilha, são os últimos a ser processados

Comment: Então, eu havia pensado em colocar o `pilha.pop()` substituindo o `pilha.peek()`, porém assim eu não perco a ideia básica do DFS? De "mergulhar" no grafo, até não haver mais vértices não-descobertos e ir realizando o backtracking?

O resultado, fazendo as substituições:
    `[ ]
    [B, D]
    [B, D, F]
    [B, D, F]
    [B, D, F, I]
    [B, D, F, I]
    [B, D, F, I]
    [B, D, F]
    [B, D]
    [B]
    [ ]`

Comment: Não é mesmo isso, não penso que percas a ideia básica do DFS. Tu vais carregando os novos nós na pilha e apenas quando tiveres visitado todos os não-visitados fazes backtrack. Se quiseres eu posso actualizar a resposta com um exemplo.

Comment: Claro, seria interessante.